# Python 2 equivelant of print(*array)

Tags: python

Can anyone suggest python 2 equivelant of python 3 statement:

```
a = [1,2,3]
print(*a)
```

Output: 1 2 3

Comment: If you `from __future__ import print_function`, you can use the 3.x print in 2.x.

Comment: ``print ' '.join(map(str, a))``?